# getDeclaredField method not defined

Tags: java, minecraft

I am working on a fix for a mod for the game minecraft. but there is a catch. The mod is not made by me, so i have to decompile it

To make a long story short, this is my first time working on obsfucated, noncomplete sources.

I am only gonna edit ONE file (out of around 1.5K).

It decompiled fine, and i edited what i wanted, but now i can't compile it. I am using the classpath variable to point it to the jar, so i can still use the classes from the rest of the game. but 2 errors exists, both involving ".getDeclaredField(s)".

Code:

```
public static Minecraft getMinecraft()
{
    try
    {
        Field field = Minecraft.getDeclaredField("a"); // Error here
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return (Minecraft)field.get(null);
    }
    catch(IllegalAccessException illegalaccessexception)
    {
        illegalaccessexception.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(NoSuchFieldException nosuchfieldexception)
    {
        nosuchfieldexception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The other case is just like this, so no need to show you that.

Error log:

```
TMIUtils.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)
location: class net.minecraft.client.Minecraft
Field field = Minecraft.getDeclaredField("a");
```

How will i go about fixing this? (keep in mind this is the first time working with getDeclaredField too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
Minecraft.class.getDeclaredField("a");
```

Perhaps it's a decompiler's error.

`getDeclaredField()` is a method of type [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), and `Minecraft.class` is a literal value of that type.